# Performance Tuning/Monitor Tool for Android (Emulator) application? (Java's VisualVm Equivalent)

Tags: android, performance

I have simple application that need to tune.
I am wondering if there is a tool to use for performance monitoring of an Android app.
I've been using VisualVM for my Java applications.

Is there an equivalent of VisualVM or any available tool to use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ADT comes with a built-in [profiler](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/ddms.html), you can track memory allocation, threads and profile methods.

[Traceview](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) is also quite useful.

Comment: These tools are now deprecated, see https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/monitor